# angular 7 *ngFor nested array iteration

Tags: angularjs

In Angular 7, I have nested array of objects as below to iterate. 1st level iteration using *ngFor does work, but nested iteration does not show up any value. Anyone help me what has to be done? Find the below code

> Sample JSON

```
const res = [ {
        2: [ 
            {id:1, cId: 2, name: 'TEST 1'},{id:2, cId: 2, name: 'TEST 2'}
          ],
        8: [ 
            {id: 10, cId: 8, name: 'TEST 10'}
        ]
    }]


<div *ngFor="let country of res[0] | keyvalue;">
   <span> {{country.key}} </span> <!-- Displayed 2 and 8 -->
   <div *ngFor="let airport of country[country.key]">
         <span>{{airport.name}}</span> <!-- name should be displayed, but nothing is coming up-->
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your html with the following

```
<div *ngFor="let country of res[0] | keyvalue;">
   <span> {{country.key}} </span> <!-- Displayed 2 and 8 -->
   <div *ngFor="let airport of country.value">
         <span>{{airport.name}}</span> <!-- name should be displayed, but nothing is coming up-->
   </div>
</div>
```

more specifically you have to replace country[country.key] with country.value

**[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5qxqmb)**